# Couchbase Java API and javascript view not returning value for a specific Key

Tags: javascript, couchbase, membase

I am using couchbase API in java

```
View view = client.getView("dev_1", "view1");
    Query query = new Query();
    query.setIncludeDocs(true);
    query.setKey(this.Key);
    ViewResponse res=client.query(view, query);
    for(ViewRow row: res)   
    {
          // Print out some infos about the document
        a=a+" "+row.getKey()+" : "+row.getValue()+"<br/>";

    }

    return a;
```

and the java script view in couchbase

```
function (doc,meta) {
  emit(meta.id,doc);
}
```

So, when I remove the statement query.setkey(this.Key) it works returns me all the tables, what am I missing here .. How can I change the function to refect only the table name mentioned in the key

Comment: 1. What is `this.Key` variable, where it defined and what value does it have?
2. What do you mean saying "table"? Couchbase doesn't have any tables. (Give an example).
3. If you use `setIncludeDocs(true);` you should use `emit(meta.id,null);` instead of `emit(meta.id,doc);`

Comment: this.Key has the tablename i.e. i have a field called table in my JSON doc, so I want to query doc.table=this.key get the result set and return it

Comment: So try to emit(doc.table,null);

Answer (score 0):

Change the map function like this:

```
      function (doc,meta) {
           emit(doc.table,null);
      }
```

it is good practice not to emit the entire document like:

```
      emit(doc.table, doc)
```

**NB: This is surprisingly important:**

i have tried using `setKey("key")` so many times from Java projects and setting the key using CouchBase Console 3.0.1's `Filter Result` dialog, but nothing get returned.

One day, i used `setInclusiveEnd` and it worked. i checked the setInclusiveEnd checkbox in CouchBase Console 3.0.1's `Filter Result` dialog and i got json output.

```
    query.setKey("whatEverKey");
    query.setInclusiveEnd(true);
```

i hope this will be helpful to others having the same issue. if anyone finds another way out, please feel free to add a comment about it.

i don't know why their documentation does not specify this.

**EXTRA**

If your json is derived from an entity class in a Java Project, make sure to include an `if statement` to test the json field for the entity class name to enclose you `emit` statement. This will avoid the key being emitted as `null`:

```
      if(doc._class == "path.to.Entity") {
          emit(doc.table, null);
      }
```